# Naming categories with using ancestry gem for a rails products catelogue with sections, categories, and subcategories functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, nested, ancestry

I'm trying to figure out how to list products in categories to achieve a result similar to this:

Phones (3)

--Smart Phones (2)

----Apple(1)

----Android (1)

--House Phones (1)

Computers (4)

--Laptops (1)

--Desktops (3)

----AMD (2)

----Intel (1)

And when I click on a category it lists the products in that category`

I watched:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation-revised

http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

and read:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

But I still don't understand how to achieve this in rails. If anyone could point me to the right direction, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: I get how it works, I just cant figure out how to name the categories. Will I have to create a categories model, and store each category_id in every product row? Then, how will I associate the categories with ancestry?

Comment: I think I got it.. Products don't have ancestry, they have belongs_to associations to categories, the categories have ancestry.